# iptables rules is not working

Tags: iptables

I've 2 VMs running Ubuntu with local addresses (`192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2`) to run some test with `iptables` as I'm new to this tool.

I want that the `.2` machine drops all incoming packets on this interface.

I've put the following rule on the `.2` : `iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -j DROP`

`iptables -S` give me

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

and `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT(policy ACCEPT)
target  prot  opt   source     destination
DROP    all   --    anywhere   anywhere
```

To see if the rule is working I firstly do a ping the `.2` machine with the `.1` and all the packets are lost wich seems normal and secondly I do on the following on the `.1` machine

```
echo -n "Hello world" > /dev/udp/192.168.1.2/3636
```

and on the `.2` machine a `tcpdump -u -i eth0 port 3636`

The packet got captured and I don't understand why. What am I missing ?

Is there a way to capture packets blocked by all the iptables rules ?

Comment: 1) are you certain that `eth0` is the correct interface? 2) you can increase the verbosity of `-L` and `-S` by adding `-v` or even `-vv` (as usual combining parameters is possible, but you have to put the `v` in front)

Comment: btw: thx for making me aware of `/dev/udp` & Co - that was complete news to me!!

Answer (score 2):

The network stack has different parts. When a packet arrives, it traverses those parts step by step, following successive network layers. *tcpdump* simply is among the first in this path to see incoming packets and among the last to see outgoing packets.

You can see this [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) schematic to get an idea (click to get full size):

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

*tcpdump*'s default capture happens quite early at AF_PACKET, while the DROP rule is in filter/INPUT.

That means that even if *tcpdump* captured the packet, *iptables* still dropped it after, but before any process could have a chance to receive it.

You can verify this by doing for example `iptables-save -c` and checking that for each packet seen in *tcpdump* you get an increment in the counter (like an additionnal `[1:39]`) before your DROP rule.

Now to capture packets dropped by *iptables* you can use an [NFLOG](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#NFLOG) logging rule right before the DROP rule, with exactly the same filter (you could use an user chain to avoid duplication, but this is just an example). You can insert this rule before your DROP rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 10
```

And capture what it got:

```
tcpdump -n -e -i nflog:10
```

With *nflog:10* here being a pseudo-interface available to *tcpdump* to retrieve those logs (on chosen group 10. All possible interfaces can be found with `tcpdump -D`). As it's not Ethernet but IPv4, despite `-e` there's won't be ethernet information like MAC address available. You can choose different *--nflog-group* values if you want to easily separate multiple captures (but you can also use *tcpdump*'s own filters for this).